# EXE remains in Task Manager after quitting

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow-foundation, quickbooks

I have an windows application written in WPF and WF which also interacts with external web services and a local copy of Quickbooks via Quickbooks API.

Everything is working nicely, however the only problem is even after we quit the windows application and Quickbooks, we still see the windows application executable sitting in the task manager.

Anyone has any idea how we can solve this?

thanks, 
badallen

Comment: Just to double check, you're sure this is the stand-alone executable still running, and not *appname*.vshost.exe?

Comment: I would try to debug the application. After you have "shut it down" (closed the main window) break the debugger to see what the now invisible application is doing. You might want to use the Microsoft symbol server to get detailed stack traces. From your description alone it is pretty hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: I suggest to look for non-background threads that are not stopped when the main application shuts down.

Comment: +1@daniel. I was going to suggest that as well. That has happened to me in the past (ie. An un-finished, non-background thread is still running).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be an issue related to [Application.ShutDownMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx)? The property might be set to [ShutDownMode.OnExplicitShutDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode.onexplicitshutdown.aspx) and there might be no call to [Application.ShutDown()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdown.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I'd look to your WF or quickbooks API hanging on their `Dispose()` calls. Sometimes network APIs are too eager to clean up properly, instead of just closing and getting out of the way.

One way to handle this is via a bg thread w/ a timeout. Something like the following

```
        Action close = api.Dispose;
        var ar = close.BeginInvoke(cb => close.EndInvoke(cb), null);
        ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(500);
```